# How to filter custom columns from SharePoint list using LINQ?

Tags: linq, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

My requirement is to get items, only from custom-columns, in a SharePoint list using LINQ.

Since my custom columns are created dynamically based on some calculations done on another SPList, it keeps increasing and decreasing in the count frequently, therefore I cannot use SPMetal.

I need to include a condition **(!(SPBuiltInFieldId.Contains(field.Id)))** to check if the items are taken only from custom fields in the following query.

```
List<SPListItem> AllResponses = (from SPListItem Response in oList.Items
                                select Response).ToList();
```

Please advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's possible to have a list item that contains only custom columns. Even if Title is not there, you'll have ID, Modified, Created, etc. Plus, there will be a number of hidden built-in columns.

If you want a list of items that contain items with custom fields, you can try something like the following, which utilizes [Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) and [Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972) methods:

```
List<SPListItem> AllResponses = 
    (from SPListItem Response in oList.Items select Response)
    .Where(item => item.Fields
        .Cast<SPField>()
        .Any(field => !SPBuiltInFieldId.Contains(field.Id)))
    .ToList();
```

This will return all items that have at least one custom field.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately this did not fulfill my requirement. The round about method that I followed is `1. Create custom columns under a group 2. LINQ query to filter the columns that belong to this group` This separates custom columns from the other default list columns, but this gives only the field names. I am new to LINQ and I do not know how to get SPListItems with this list of fields. Now what I want is `List<SPListItem> AllItems = (from SPListItem item in oList.Items select {the fields that are in AllFields list}).ToList();` Please help. Thanks!